# How to replace all those Special Characters with white spaces in python?

Tags: python, replace, special-characters, whitespace, text-files

How to replace all those special characters with white spaces in python ?

I have a list of names of a company . . .

Ex:-[myfiles.txt]

> MY company.INC
>
> Old Wine pvt
>
> master-minds ltd
>
> "apex-labs ltd"
>
> "India-New corp"
>
> Indo-American pvt/ltd

Here, as per the above example . . . I need all the special characters[-,",/,.] in the file `myfiles.txt` must be replaced with a single white space and saved into another text file `myfiles1.txt`.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: There is no non-special character. If there were one, there would be a smallest non-special character. Which would make it special.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you mean to change everything non-alphanumeric, you can do this on the command line:

```
cat foo.txt | sed "s/[^A-Za-z0-99]/ /g" > bar.txt
```

Or in Python with the `re` module:

```
import re
original_string = open('foo.txt').read()
new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', original_string)
open('bar.txt', 'w').write(new_string)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import string

specials = '-"/.' #etc
trans = string.maketrans(specials, ' '*len(specials))
#for line in file
cleanline = line.translate(trans)
```

e.g.

```
>>> line = "Indo-American pvt/ltd"
>>> line.translate(trans)
'Indo American pvt ltd'
```

Comment: This is great !!!! but i want it to be saved into a textfile automatically . . . .

like every line from myfile.txt must be read and should be saved into myfiles1.txt after getting them replaced

Comment: then just add a line after the conversion to do exactly that!

Comment: @Yeshu91 if f is your filehandle (e.g. f=open('cleanfile.txt', 'w') then just add f.write(cleanline) at the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
strs = "how much for the maple syrup? $20.99? That's ricidulous!!!"
strs = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!]',r'',strs) #for remove particular special char
strs = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]',r'',strs) #for remove all characters
strs=''.join(c if c not in map(str,range(0,10)) else '' for c in strs) #for remove numbers
strs = re.sub('  ',' ',strs) #for remove extra spaces
print(strs) 

Ans: how much for the maple syrup Thats ricidulous
```

Answer (score 1):

While maketrans is the fastes way to do it, I never remerber the syntax. Since speed is rarely an issue and I know regular expression, I would tend to do this:

```
>>> line = "-[myfiles.txt] MY company.INC"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ',line)
'  myfiles txt  MY company INC'
```

This has the additional benefit of declaring the character you accept instead of the one you reject, which feels easier in this case.

Of couse if you are using non ASCII caracters you'll have to go back to removing the characters you reject. If there are just punctuations sign, you can do:

```
>>> import string
>>> chars = re.escape(string.punctuation)
>>> re.sub(r'['+chars+']', ' ',line)
'  myfiles txt  MY company INC'
```

But you'll notice

Answer (score 0):

At first i thought to provide a string.maketrans/translate example, but maybe you are using some utf-8 encoded strings and the ord() sorted translate-table will blow in your face, so i thought about another solution:

```
conversion = '-"/.'
text =  f.read()
newtext = ''
for c in text:
    newtext += ' ' if c in conversion else c
```

It's not the fastest way, but easy to grasp and modify.

So if your text is non-ascii you could decode `conversion` and the text-strings to unicode and afterwards reencode in whichever encoding you want to.