# Remove special characters from csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

There seems to something on this topic already ([How to replace all those Special Characters with white spaces in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800815/how-to-replace-all-those-special-characters-with-white-spaces-in-python)), but I can't figure this simple task out for the life of me.

I have a .CSV file with 75 columns and almost 4000 rows. I need to replace all the 'special characters' ($ # & * ect) with '_' and write to a new file. Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv

input = open('C:/Temp/Data.csv', 'rb')
lines = csv.reader(input)
output = open('C:/Temp/Data_out1.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)

conversion = '-"/.$'
text =  input.read()
newtext = '_'
for c in text:
    newtext += '_' if c in conversion else c
    writer.writerow(c)

input.close()
output.close()
```

All this succeeds in doing is to write everything to the output file as a single column, producing over 65K rows. Additionally, the special characters are still present!

Sorry for the redundant question.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might do something like

```
import csv

with open("special.csv", "rb") as infile, open("repaired.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    conversion = set('_"/.$')
    for row in reader:
        newrow = [''.join('_' if c in conversion else c for c in entry) for entry in row]
        writer.writerow(newrow)
```

which turns

```
$ cat special.csv
th$s,2.3/,will-be
fixed.,even.though,maybe
some,"shoul""dn't",be
```

(note that I have a quoted value) into

```
$ cat repaired.csv 
th_s,2_3_,will-be
fixed_,even_though,maybe
some,shoul_dn't,be
```

---

Right now, your code is reading in the entire text into one big line:

```
text =  input.read()
```

Starting from a `_` character:

```
newtext = '_'
```

Looping over every single character in `text`:

```
for c in text:
```

Add the corrected character to `newtext` (very slowly):

```
    newtext += '_' if c in conversion else c
```

And then write the *original* character (?), as a column, to a new csv:

```
    writer.writerow(c)
```

.. which is unlikely to be what you want. :^)

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more on how `newrow = [''.join('_' if c in conversion else c for c in entry) for entry in row]` this line of code is functioning ?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't seem to need to deal with CSV's in particular (as long as the special characters aren't your column delimiters).

```
lines = []
with open('C:/Temp/Data.csv', 'r') as input:
    lines = input.readlines()

conversion = '-"/.$'
newtext = '_'
outputLines = []
for line in lines:
    temp = line[:]
    for c in conversion:
        temp = temp.replace(c, newtext)
    outputLines.append(temp)

with open('C:/Temp/Data_out1.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in outputLines:
        output.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: I think your loop logic is wrong: that will output `len(conversion)` lines for each line, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the bug pointed out by @Nisan.H and the valid point made by @dckrooney that you may not need to treat the file in a special way in this case just because it is a CSV file (but see my comment below):

1. `writer.writerow()` should take a sequence of strings, each of which would be written out separated by commas (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)). In your case you are writing a single string.
2. This code is setting up to read from 'C:/Temp/Data.csv' in *two* ways - through `input` and through `lines` but it only actually reads from `input` (therefore the code does not deal with the file as a CSV file anyway).
3. The code appends characters to `newtext` and writes out each version of that variable. Thus, the first version of `newtext` would be 1 character long, the second 2 characters long, the third 3 characters long, etc.

Finally, given that a CSV file *can* have quote marks in it, it may actually be necessary to deal with the input file specifically as a CSV to avoid replacing quote marks that you want to keep, e.g. quote marks that are there to protect commas that exist within fields of the CSV file. In that case, it would be necessary to process each field of the CSV file individually, then write each row out to the new CSV file.

Comment: Fantastic. This worked! Thank you all for walking me through this.

Comment: @Jenny: Glad to help. If I were you I'd be inclined to tick DSM's answer as correct, as it is the most complete and detailed. That would also save other people seeing this question and thinking it hasn't yet been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
s = open('myfile.cv','r').read()

chars = ('$','%','^','*') # etc
for c in chars:
  s = '_'.join( s.split(c) )

out_file = open('myfile_new.cv','w')
out_file.write(s)
out_file.close()
```

Comment: if you want to write rows for whatever reason, then just do `rows = s.split('\n')` after the loop