# Removing various characters from (.csv or .txt) file Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file which looks like:

```
['NAME' " 'RA_I1'" " 'DEC_I1'" " 'Mean_I1'" " 'Median_I1'" " 'Mode_I1'" ...]"
```

where this string carries on for (I think) 95 entries, the entire file is over a thousand rows deep. I want to remove all the characters: `[ ' "` and just have everything separated by a single white space entry (`' '`).
So far I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_table('slap.txt')
    for char in df1:
        if char in " '[":
            df1.replace(char, '')

print df1
```

Where I'm just 'testing' the code to see if it will do what I want it to, it's not. I'd like to implement it on the entire file, but I'm not sure how.

*I've checked [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750628/remove-special-characters-from-csv-file-using-python) out but not quite getting it to work for my purposes. I've also played with the linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750628/remove-special-characters-from-csv-file-using-python), the only problem with it seems to be that all the entries are spaced twice rather than just once....*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something you ought to be able to grab with a (not particularly pretty) regular expression in the sep argument of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
In [11]: pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\[\'|\'\"\]|[ \'\"]*', header=None)
Out[11]:
    0     1      2       3        4          5        6   7
0 NaN  NAME  RA_I1  DEC_I1  Mean_I1  Median_I1  Mode_I1 NaN
```

*You can play about with the regular expression til it truly fits your needs.*

To explain this one:

```
sep = ('\[\'  # each line startswith ['  (the | means or)
       '|\'\"\]'  # endswith '"] (at least the one I had)
       '|[ \'\"]+')  # this is the actual delimiter, the + means at least one, so it's a string of ", ' and space in any order.
```

You can see this hack has left a NaN column at either end. The main reason this is pretty awful is because of the inconsistency of your "csv", I would definitely recommend cleaning it up, of course, one way to do that is just to use pandas and then `to_csv`. If it's generated by someone else... complain (!).

Comment: @tom actually that is a lot better! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
string.strip(s[, chars])
```

?

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html