# remove some character in python from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset about Indonesia recipe with 3 columns (first column is recipe name, second column is ingredient, third column is step).

In the second and third column, there is some special character wsuch as `'#'` and `'/'`, how do I remove them? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750628/remove-special-characters-from-csv-file-using-python) but it's showing some errors. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g95s58tqahg3nt7/dataset-ayam-baru.csv?dl=0) is the dataset!

This is my code:

```
import csv

input = open('dataset-ayam-baru.csv', 'rb')
lines = csv.reader(input)
output = open('new_dataset.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)

conversion = '-"/.$'
text =  input.read()
newtext = '_'
for c in text:
    newtext += '_' if c in conversion else c
    writer.writerow(c)

    input.close()
    output.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

> `TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-28-05d606ed80df> in <module>() 10 newtext = '' 11 for c in text: ---> 12 newtext += '' if c in conversion else c 13 writer.writerow(c) 14`
>
> `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`

Comment: Can you post the error log over here.

Comment: here is the error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-05d606ed80df> in <module>()
     10 newtext = '_'
     11 for c in text:
---> 12     newtext += '_' if c in conversion else c
     13     writer.writerow(c)
     14 

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

Comment: Please add the code **you** used

Comment: i've been aded the code i used

Comment: then is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you are loading the file as bytes. You need to put the "rt" instead of "wb" when you open the file.

From the stackoverflow question you cited, a working answer for me is:

```
import csv

with open("dataset-ayam-baru.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as infile, open("new_dataset.csv", "w") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    conversion = set('_"/.$')
    for row in reader:
        newrow = [''.join('_' if c in conversion else c for c in entry) for entry in row]
        writer.writerow(newrow)
```

Important: the encoding of the input file! I had to convert it to ANSI to make it work, because you need to know in advance the encoding of the dataset (i.e., utf-8).

The followup question (the one regarding the bytes and the encoding) is there: [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Comment: Hi, thank you for solution, but I got new error : charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3291: character maps to <undefined>, what is it possible about?

Comment: Hello, it depends on the encoding of your original csv. It is mandatory that you know the encoding of the file beforehand, it cannot be inferred. I edited the answer adding the parameter "encoding" to the open() function. If you do not know the encoding of the file, you have to convert it to a known encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Here i found somewhere to remove the special character, in case someone may need it.

```
def give_emoji_free_text(text):
    allchars = [str for str in text]
    emoji_list = [c for c in allchars if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI]
    clean_text = ' '.join([str for str in text.split() if not any(i in str for i in emoji_list)])
   return clean_text

    for i in range(len(data['Title'])):
        data['Ingredients'][i] =  give_emoji_free_text(data['Ingredients'].get_value(i))
        data['Title'][i] =  give_emoji_free_text(data['Title'].get_value(i))
        data['Steps'][i] =  give_emoji_free_text(data['Steps'].get_value(i))
```

Thank you.